# ajax receive data back from php (so can remove element(s) )

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am passing a form element via ajax and when it comes back I need to remove the elements that were "selected" (checkboxes) but the success comes back empty (data)

My code:

```
$('#unsub_list_form').on('submit', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
 var authorid_form = $('#user_list_item').val();
 var data = {
  action: 'wt4_ajax_unsub_multi',
  sub_userid: <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>,
  authorid: authorid_form,
 };
 $.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $('#'+authorid).remove();
  }
 });
});
```

I can send messages back too the ajax by echo'ing but I need to get my original data back so I can then manipulate the html.

a few hours of googling hasn't come up with anything concrete as I am still new to ajax (in the last 48 hours) so might have missed something obvious.

Comment: you can either $data from php and get it in data in success, or you can use the same data object you sent in ajax, if you get success..